# Selenium not inputting the whole text into a text box

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, salesforce-lightning

I am using Selenium to clear out the existing Shipping Address fields of a Salesforce Account object and to assign new values. I am coding in C# and running on Visual Studio 2019.

I am getting cases where the textboxes are not getting fully populated.

My code is below.

```
private string shippingStreet = "56789 Liberty Street";     // 80 character limit
private string shippingCity = "Toronto";                    // 40 character limit
private string shippingState = "ON";                        // 80 character limit
private string shippingZip = "87654";                       // 20 character limit
private string shippingCountry = "Canada";                  // 80 character limit


 IWebElement shStreet = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//textarea[@placeholder='Shipping Street']"));
 shStreet.Clear();
 shStreet.SendKeys(shippingStreet); 
              
 IWebElement shCity = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@placeholder='Shipping City']"));
 shCity.Clear();
 shCity.SendKeys(shippingCity);
              
IWebElement shState = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@placeholder='Shipping State/Province']"));
shState.Clear();
shState.SendKeys(shippingState);
              
IWebElement shZip = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@placeholder='Shipping Zip/Postal Code']"));
shZip.Clear();
shZip.SendKeys(shippingZip);
              
IWebElement shCountry = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@placeholder='Shipping Country']"));
shCountry.Clear();
shCountry.SendKeys(shippingCountry);
```

Please see the screenshot.

[image]

I fix this issue by adding an extra space after city, state, zip code, and country but I was wondering if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method:

Just call it and add the xpath: WaitForElementDisplayed_byXPathTime("//myPath");

```
    WaitForElementDisplayed_byXPathTime

    public static void WaitForElementDisplayed_byXPathTime(string value)
    {
            var wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));
            wait.Until(webDriver => webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(value)).Displayed);

    }
```

The other thing I have done on these is create a new type method for individual characters like you would on mobile. This just slows it down a bit.

```
    public static void TypeCharsIndividually(IWebElement element, string expectedValue)
    {
        //use your code for element displayed and element enabled      
        element.Click();
        element.Clear();
        foreach (char c in expectedValue)
        {
            element.SendKeys(c.ToString());
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
```

java click

```
        public static void ClickJava(IWebElement element)
    {
        IJavaScriptExecutor executor = driver IJavaScriptExecutor;
        executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
    }
```

WaitForElement

```
                public static bool WaitForElementDisplayed_byXPath(string path)
    {
        var result = true;
        try { _wait.Until(webDriver => driver.FindElement(By.XPath(path)).Displayed); }
        catch (StaleElementReferenceException) { WaitForElementDisplayed_byXPath(path); }
        catch (NoSuchElementException) { WaitForElementDisplayed_byXPath(path); }
        catch (WebDriverTimeoutException) { result = false; }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Typing characters individually works but then it stays stuck in the first textbox. Is the threading messing up the flow?

Comment: what happens when you step through it in debug mode? what is your error message?

Comment: When I run the Test in Debug mode, i comes back with  OpenQA.Selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException : element click intercepted: Element <input lightning-input_input="" type="text" id="input-352" maxlength="40" placeholder="Shipping City" name="city" class="slds-input"> is not clickable at point (698, 685). Other element would receive the click:

Comment: You can try adding an offset to the click or you can also try a javaclick. I added a java click to my answer above. What does your xpath look like for the element?

Comment: Do you mean I should call the ClickJava instead of element.click in TypeCharsIndividually?

Comment: yes - var ele = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(...)); element.ClickJava(ele); Can you add the html marlup in your question and show the xpath you are using?

Comment: The problem is not the XPath. It is able to find the controls correctly. The problem is why it is not filling them in fully. When I pt a debug point into element.SendKeys(c.ToString()); and step through it, the textboxes get filled in correctly, so we need to somethow slow it down just like the debugger is doing.

Comment: There is a thread sleep on the type chars individually that is extremely low at 100ms. A 1000ms is a second so that can be adjusted for that method. My concern is that you are already on the page and adding text so all elements should be found already. I added a wait for element displayed in my answer.

Comment: The weird thing is it is writing "Toronto" and then deleting the last letter so only"Toront" remains. Ditto for "ON" and "O"

Answer (score 0):

This is a Salesforce issue. I see the problem even when i am manually updating a shipping address field and I tab to another field.